# HexDecode // HexEncode

Tags: javascript, arrays, unicode, hex

The problem is that I try to convert one array into another by means of HexDecode and HexEncode. Everything is working well, until the moment, when I try to convert two characters e.g. 005002bb [Latin T'] into one character e.g. a760 [Ꝡ]. The converter works, but it retains ' (apostrophe), which I want to disappear. I need to treat T' as one unit and to remain one unit in the output

I think that I tried everything what I know

```
<script>
    String.prototype.hexDecode = function () 
    {
        var j;
        var hexes = this.match( /.{1,4}/g ) || [];
        var back = "";
        var lexesLength=hexes.length;
        for ( j = 0; j < lexesLength; j++ ) 
        {
            back += String.fromCharCode( parseInt( hexes[ j ], 16 ) );
        }

        return back;
    }   

    String.prototype.hexEncode = function () 
    {
        var hex, i;

        var result = [];
        var length = this.length;
        for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 
        {
            hex = this.charCodeAt( i ).toString( 16 );
            result.push( ( "000" + hex ).slice( -4 ) );
        }

        return result;
    }

    Array.prototype.romanceltic = function () 
    {
        var roman = ['005402bb', '0041'];

        var celtic = ['a760', 'A762'];

        var length = this.length;
        var answer = '';
        var char;
        var index;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char = this[ i ];
            index = roman.indexOf( char );
            answer += ( index != -1 ) ? celtic [ index ].hexDecode() : char.hexDecode();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    $(function() 
    {
        $( "input" ).click( function ( e ) 
        {
            var answer;
            var content = $("#input").val();
            switch ( $( this ).attr( "id" ) ) 
            {
                case "romanceltic":
                    {
                        answer = content.hexEncode().romanceltic();
                    }
                break;                      
            }
            $("#output" ).val(answer);
        } )
    } );

</script>
```

something like that

I haven't error messages. It works, but the output is not that I am waiting for. As I understand the code can't treat '005402bb' as a whole unit. 
I wanted to say the input is T' , the output is Ꝡ. In other words, the input consists of two characters (T+' or any other +') and the output, which I want to get, should be one character (Ꝡ or any other). I inserted additionally the full script and another character A -> Ꝣ [A762] and as you can see the code converts it correctly, but I don't understand what happens with the first sample, why I can't convert T+' to Ꝡ?

Comment: Can you show a sample of expected output for a given input? Also note that `U+0054` is T, not P.

Comment: Exactly, U+0054 is T. I wanted to say the input is T' , the output is Ꝡ. In other words, the input consists of two characters (T+' or any other +') and the output, which I want to get, should be one character (Ꝡ or any other).

Comment: Please edit the question to include this example. Ideally, you should show some code that calls the function, showing what it would return if it worked as expected.

Comment: I can't see how this code could work - even for the partial result you imply you are getting - how will a single character, int the var `char` ever match the encoded bytes in the `roman` array?

Comment: I inserted the whole script, which I use to convert characters and the additional letter in the script to show that it works with regards to character to character conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the code and come to the conclusion that you are over-complicating things. This appears to be the implementation of a poor man's input method editor. Simply use the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

```
var content = 'TʻA';
content = content.replace(/Tʻ/gu, 'Ꝡ');
content = content.replace(/A/gu, 'Ꝣ');
console.log(content);
// ꝠꝢ
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Your option is of course easier and I am really thankful for that. But, I want to understand, why the above-mentioned code is not working, where is a mistake?(((

Comment: @Nikky, use a debugger. The bug is in line `index = roman.indexOf(char);` where char is string `0054` which is not an element in `roman`. The real problem is that you advance 1 character at a time when you instead should look at the input data length and then decide how many characters to advance accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I am rather stupid. Have I to use val().length method to determine it? If it is not difficult, can you explain, how can I change it?

Comment: As about the replace method, I tried it. For instance, content = content.replace(/Tʻ/g, 'Tik').replace(/A/g, 'Ⴀk').replace(/P/g, 'Pik').replace(/Pʻ/g, 'Pak'); But the output was not as I waited, e.g. it works for Tʻ, but it doesn't work for Pʻ in case of Pʻ it returns Pik with apostrophe. I understand that there is P as well, but I need P with apostrophe to be processed together as a whole. I tried insert in the code T\ʻ as well , but it didn't work as well.

Comment: In case of common prefixes such as `P` and `Pʻ`, put the *longest* first, thus: `… replace(/Pʻ/g, 'Pak').replace(/P/g, 'Pik') …` The chain of replacements is evaluated from left to right and the regular expression tries to consume as many characters as possible, meaning `Pʻ` matched with both characters and is replaced first, leaving `P` for the next pass.

Comment: By the way, that character is not an apostrophe, but `U+02BB ‹ʻ› \N{MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA}`.